# Change values in array by forms values send

Tags: php, foreach, flat-file

I have 2 arrays.
The first array has the table names for a simple DB in text.
The second array has the values of each table.

When I launch my form the field value send from form and has the equal value of tables array, take the value send from the form.

**The Script :**

```
  <?php        
    if($_POST[send]=="ok") {
        /// The structure it´s that and fixed , in the array_1 and 2 /// 


$tables="name,phone,alias"; 
       $values="Jhon,55543232,johny25";

       /// Explode values in each case ///
       $exp_tables=explode(",",$tables); 
       $exp_values=explode(",",$values);
       /// Array for get values for each field /// 
       $i=0;
       foreach($exp_tables as $exp_table) { ${$exp_table}[]="".$exp_values[$i].""; $i++; }
         /// Bucle for get the result if vars send by form equal to the other vars and change by new value send form the form ///
          foreach($exp_tables as $table) {
             foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {   
                  if($table=="".$key."") 
                    { 
                      print "".$_POST[$table]."";        
                    } 
                  else { print "".${$table}{0}."";}

                }
             }
         }
     ?>
```

**The html form**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value"send" />
<input type="hidden" name="send" value="ok" />
</form>
```

In the form I have "name" in the first field and in the array tables I have one field also called name.

When I send the form I must get this:

```
Jhon(change value by the value from the form),55543232,johny25
```

The Problem it´s repeat all time values and no get the results ok.

My question is: How can I fix this for put the values I send from form and change when the other values has the same name as in the array tables, but no works very well.

Comment: Can you tell me what output do you expect? Are you saying $name value should be replaces with form's value?

Comment: Yes right , the form the same name as in the array change value by the form value send

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your variables `$tables` an `$values` are no arrays but strings.

An array looks like

`array(value, value, value)`

or

`array( key=> value, key=> value, key value)`

In your case you could use

```
$tables=array('name','phone','alias'); 
$values=array('Jhon','55543232','johny25');
   //or, to make even simpler
$values=array('name'=>'Jhon','phone'=>'55543232','alias'=>'johny25');
```

Then, if you only want to output the name and check if the name is different from that in the array, you simply do:

```
if($_POST['name']==$values['name']){
     print "".$_POST['name']."";        
     } 
 else{
     print "".$values['name']."";
     }
```